# How can I stop my windows opening with a wide proportional frame?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, microsoft-outlook-2010, evernote

I've done a reinstallation of Windows 7 Ultimate and I'm now finding that window sizes for various programs open with a very wide frame size (roughly 16:9 proportion) - even when I've resized and closed the windows. It doesn't happen for every program, but is a noticeable issue with Windows Explorer, Evernote and Outlook so far.

How can I stop window sizes being reset each time I open a program?

Answer (score 2):

When closing a Windows for a specific application, say Internet Explorer, first resize it to the size you like all the new Windows for that program to app at, and then while pressing CTRL close the window. This setting will be applied to all future Windows for that program.